# How to get tz identifier string from utc offset

Tags: ruby, tzinfo

How do I get timezone in tzinfo format i.e `America/Toronto` from utc offset in seconds while taking into consideration the DST changes.

For example DST settings last changed at 2:00 AM , March 9,2014. See offset difference

```
Varinder $ irb

2.1.0 :001 > Time.local(2014,03,9,1,59) 
 => 2014-03-09 01:59:00 -0500 

2.1.0 :002 > Time.local(2014,03,9,2,00) 
 => 2014-03-09 03:00:00 -0400 
2.1.0 :003 >

2.1.0 :006 > Time.local(2014,03,9,2,00).zone
 => "EDT"  # I need America/Toronto format
```

For both these time examples calculated tzinfo string should be same because only difference in offset is due to DST.

Comment: use this http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Time.html#method-i-zone .. Like `Time.local(2014,03,9,1,59).zone`.. or `Time.local(2014,03,9,1,59).strftime('%Z')`..

Comment: Yes `time.zone` returns `EDT` but I need `America/Toronto`

Comment: I am in India.. Don't have idea about others :p

Comment: For India too, it would return `IST` not `Asia/kolkata` :P

Comment: Oops!! You know my city too ? :-) How come?

Comment: While you have an answer for this post ping me, I would also like to see the answer.

Comment: This would be almost impossible as the same time zone is shared across many countries/regions, you can have a look at https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2ec916ba1ec560b054e5e32ebe8f94ea891816b8/activesupport/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to figure out the DST issues, but this might get you there (I'm in PST...)

```
> offset = Time.local(2014,03,9,1,59).utc_offset
=> -28800
> ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.select{|tz| tz.utc_offset == offset}
=> [#<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x007fbcacd075a8 @name="Pacific Time (US & Canada)", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: America/Los_Angeles>, @current_period=#<TZInfo::TimezonePeriod: #<TZInfo::TimezoneTransitionInfo: #<TZInfo::TimeOrDateTime: 1394359200>,#<TZInfo::TimezoneOffsetInfo: -28800,3600,PDT>>,#<TZInfo::TimezoneTransitionInfo: #<TZInfo::TimeOrDateTime: 1414918800>,#<TZInfo::TimezoneOffsetInfo: -28800,0,PST>>>>, #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x007fbcacd07530 @name="Tijuana", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: America/Tijuana>, @current_period=#<TZInfo::TimezonePeriod: #<TZInfo::TimezoneTransitionInfo: #<TZInfo::TimeOrDateTime: 1394359200>,#<TZInfo::TimezoneOffsetInfo: -28800,3600,PDT>>,#<TZInfo::TimezoneTransitionInfo: #<TZInfo::TimeOrDateTime: 1414918800>,#<TZInfo::TimezoneOffsetInfo: -28800,0,PST>>>>]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
zone_abbr = Time.local(2014,03,9,2,00).zone
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.
  all.
  select{|tz| tz.tzinfo.current_period.abbreviation.to_s == zone_abbr}.
  map(&:tzinfo).
  map(&:name)
```

For `"EDT"` this code returns `["America/New_York", "America/Indiana/Indianapolis"]`